# Domain of the multiplication of 2 functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that $f(x)=\sqrt{9-x}$
and $g(x)=\sqrt{1/(9-x^2)}$

The question is what is the domain of $f\circ g$?

I can see that the domain of $f(x)$  is  $(-\inf,9]$ and the domain of $g(x)$ is $(-3,3)$.  However, it is not clear how I go about determining this answer since it doesn't appear to be easily graphable.

Comment: Do you mean $g(x)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{9-x^2}}?$

Comment: That operation $\;f\circ g\;$ is usually called "composition of functions", as "multiplication of functions" is usually reserved, in this context, to other thing.

Comment: Well, isn't the way I wrote it for $g(x)$ the same as the way you wrote it?  I viewed this as a multiplication of functions.

Comment: The title must be changed to "Domain of the composition of 2 functions"

Answer (score 1):

You need $9-1/\sqrt{9-x^2}$ to be non-negative. Or $81(9-x^2)\geq 1$ or $728/81\geq x^2$ or $-\frac{\sqrt{728}}{9}\leq x\leq \frac{\sqrt{728}}{9}$. Or $-2.99794168\leq x\leq 2.99794168$

Comment: Ok, that is the answer given; however, I don't understand how you got there. How did you get the part after "you need" ???  If I could see this part I could understand the answer.

Comment: I'm assuming this composition is the multiplication of the 2 functions, correct?

Comment: no.. the composition is :
$f\circ g=\sqrt{9-g(x)}=...$

Comment: oh.  The composition is f of g of x?  In otherwords, everywhere there is an x in $f(x)$ put in $g(x)$?